# Does OS know the process state?

Tags: process, operating-system, kernel

Is all the `process state` such as new, ready, running, waiting and terminated are recognized by the `operating system` kernel or is it for the convenience of understanding? If it is recognized by operating system, how will it do it?

Comment: This comment is for people who down voted. I want to know why it is down voted? what is wrong with it?

Comment: How can one write a code in the place where it is not required?? Do u think stack overflow is only a forum which is used to answer only the coding problem ?? Do you think the core technically deep driven scenarios like this are important to be addressed???

Comment: For another point-of-view regarding the downvotes: Your question is vague/unclear. Not sure what you're talking about, with process state. Also, not even clear what OS you're referring to. And not clear what you're asking at the end, by "how will it do it?" I've read, and re-read the question several times, and still am unclear what you're asking. If you feel you can clarify it, you should edit your question accordingly. But, no need to get angry with people for downvoting a question.

Comment: @Extricate not all questions should have code, and no where he mentioned he wants us to write code for him. Don't just assume things and deter people from asking.
Dear OP, yes, the OS knows the state of each process, it actually changes them. Kernel keeps data structures which hold the state of a process as well. So it can access it and check the state of a process.

Comment: @David Makogon It is a generic question. If it is unclear, people like you can ask for the clarification in the comment section & then they are free to down-vote. I am not angry, I just want to know why it is down-voted as for every down-vote they is deduction in reputation.

Comment: @ Tony Tannous Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The process state you are talking about (in contrast to the context, what is called a process state as well in some literature) is solely needed by the OS itself. It is a bookkeeping instrument. As such, it introduces an overhead in hope to get (a.o) a performance gain at other places. E.g., by considering ready processes only, the OS avoids to switch to processes that would only yield to the next one (what would generate superfluous context switches).

The implementation of the concept may differ. Not always the PCB has an explicit data field for the process state. Frequently, the state is implemented by different queues, where processes are sorted to. Sometimes, OS have even an redundant representation of the process state. The representation is a matter of efficiency: E.g. if the OS seeks for some ready process (not caring which), a queue has a complexity of O(1) while a list of PCB with explicit states would require O(n).

To summarize: If the OS wouldn't be aware of the process states they would be superfluous. In what way the state is implemented and how it used differs from system to system.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the question here is that process states a entirely system specific.

Your first question is largely correct that system states are largely pedagogical constructs for "convenience of understanding."

The operating system has to know the state of the process. That is likely to be maintainted in a variety of ways, including state variables and queues.